# strange text issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have big file data containing this kind of strange text i try to del (ctrl-f) but it take too much is there is functions or formula solve this issue

[image: 1]example for issue from my sheet

Comment: I made an edit to the question but it looks like you've reverted back. Please put your question in the body of your question and not in the title. My thoughts about a solution is if this is HUGE data, then don't do this exercise in excel. Consider a text editor like Notepad++ or perhaps python or similar scripting language to clean your data before allowing excel to open it.

Comment: thank for edit and i will take your advice about the issue